# Change array from button inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have 3 buttons with `let link of links`

```
links = [
    {
      name: "Link 1",
      id: "number1"
    },
    {
      name: 'Link 2',
      id: "number2"
    }
    {
      name: "Link 3",
      id: "number3"
    }
  ]
```

They render 3 button in HTML.

I have a DIV with "let card of number1":

```
number1 = [
    {
      name: 'IT',
      address: 'Tokyo 4',
    },
    {
      name: 'Computer',
      address: 'Tokyo 4',
    },
    {
      name: 'Garden',
      address: 'Tokyo 4',
    },
    {
      name: 'Cars',
      address: 'Tokyo 4',
    }
  ]
```

And they render DIV with H1 `{{ card.name }}` and P with `{{ card.address }}`

But, how change `let card of number1` to `let card of number2` when I click on the button number 2?
Like this:

```
(click)="change number1 to number2" - when I click button number 2 etc
```

PLUNKER:
https://plnkr.co/edit/MfSx9MjoVtHprFtBHKDZ?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An other approach:

**HTML:**

```
 <li *ngFor="let link of links; let i = index">
      <button (click)="setNumber(i)">{{ link.name }}</button>
 </li>
```

**Typescript:**

```
...
number;
....
constructor(){
    this.number=this.number1
}

...
setNumber(index){
  console.log(index)
  switch(index){
    case 0:
      this.number = this.number1;
      break;
    case 1:
      this.number = this.number2;
      break;
    case 2:
      this.number = this.number3
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/32JS9QPSiYqXGDbJuWqa?p=preview)**

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 0):

Point to a different array variable and switch the reference on button click. [This is your plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qpXABoPL40UrhKDuQ8V6?p=preview) doing that.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <li *ngFor="let link of links">
      <button (click)="updateLinks(link.id)">{{ link.name }}</button>
    </li>

    <div *ngFor="let card of numbers">
      <h1>{{ card.name }}</h1>
      <p>{{ card.address }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {

  numbers: any[];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.numbers = this.number1;
  }

  updateLinks(linkId: string){
    this.numbers = this[linkId] as any[];
  }

  links = [
    {
      name: "Link 1",
      id: "number1"
    },
    {
      name: 'Link 2',
      id: "number2"
    }
    {
      name: "Link 3",
      id: "number3"
    }
  ]



  number1 = [
    {
      name: 'IT',
      address: 'IT Number 1',
    },
    {
      name: 'Computer',
      address: 'Computer Number 1',
    },
    {
      name: 'Garden',
      address: 'Garder Number 1',
    },
    {
      name: 'Cars',
      address: 'Cars Number 1',
    }
  ]



  number2 = [
    {
      name: 'IT',
      address: 'IT Number 2',
    },
    {
      name: 'Computer',
      address: 'Computer Number 2',
    },
    {
      name: 'Garden',
      address: 'Garder Number 2',
    },
    {
      name: 'Cars',
      address: 'Cars Number 2',
    }
  ]



  number3 = [
    {
      name: 'IT',
      address: 'IT Number 3',
    },
    {
      name: 'Computer',
      address: 'Computer Number 3',
    },
    {
      name: 'Garden',
      address: 'Garder Number 3',
    },
    {
      name: 'Cars',
      address: 'Cars Number 3',
    }
  ]


}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple buttons and displaying/hiding them conditionnally ?

```
  <button *ngIf="arrayNumber === 1" (click)="myFirstFunction()"></button>
  <button *ngIf="arrayNumber === 2" (click)="mySecondFunction()"></button>
```